# How to make breaklines the result from PythonTeX ?

Tags: line-breaking, python

I try make a document with use PythonTeX like this :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
\py{2014/2009}
\end{verbatim}
\begin{pyconsole}
2**2014
\end{pyconsole}
\end{document}
```

But i get .pdf like this : 
[image: no breaklines]
**How to make a breaklines the result from PythonTeX** like this :

[image: breaklines]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update 2019-10-17:** PythonTeX has had automatic line breaking just like `minted` for a while now. In both cases the line breaking is implemented in [`fvextra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fvextra?lang=en), which extends `fancyvrb`. Wrapping a long number can now be accomplished using something like `\fvset{breaklines, breakafter=0123456789}` (general `fancyvrb`/`fvextra` setting), `\setpythontexfv{breaklines, breakafter=0123456789}` (restrict to PythonTeX), or `\begin{pyconsole}[][breaklines, breakafter=0123456789]` (restrict to current environment).

---

PythonTeX currently doesn't support automatic line breaking. I've recently been adding automatic line breaking at spaces to the development version of `minted`, and will be adding that to PythonTeX soon. But that won't do what you want, because you want to wrap something that doesn't contain spaces.

For now, one solution is to modify `pythontex2.py` (or `pythontex3.py`, depending on which Python version you are using). Replace line 2523 in the most recent version with

```
processed = highlight('\n'.join([textwrap.fill(x) for x in console_content.splitlines(True)]), lexer, formatter)
```

I will look into adding this sort of wrapping as a built-in feature in the future.

Comment: ok , breaklines is success,

Comment: Hello Mr. Poore, is the mentioned linebreaking feature already implemented? My situation is simillar as OP; I am lloking for linebreaks within pyblock environment.

Comment: @TomášKruliš Yes, PythonTeX has line breaking now. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @G.Poore Thank you very much Mr. Poore. Please, allow me now to thank you for your wonderfull work to allow running python in LaTeX. For me, it helps so much and had opened an entire new world of possibilities. Thank you

Comment: Is it possible to get a linebreak in a `\pyv{}`command ?

Comment: @jowe_19 Linebreaks don't work inline with `\pyv`, etc., yet. If you need inline breaks, you could use `\Verb` from `fvextra` if you can do without highlighting, or `\mintinline` from `minted`.

Comment: Could you please explain the meaning of `breakafter` argument?

Comment: @grwlf `breaklines` only allows breaks after spaces by default. `breakafter` allows breaks after whatever additional characters are specified. It's useful when there are few or no spaces, so the default behavior doesn't produce good results.